# How can I create an instance of a singleton just for the purpose of implementing it?

Tags: c#, singleton

The mere fact that I'm asking this question and don't see it anywhere leads me to believe my design/thinking is flawed, so that very well may be the case and my implementation could be greatly improved.

I have a singleton class ([like here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)) in which I'm building some stuff to use for a bunch of test classes. I'm using a singleton so that my testing objects don't have to be repeatedly built in each testing class. Now, there are some fields such as `BaseEconomy` assigned inside the singleton which I need in each test class. Thus, each test class has an Initialization method like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
        {
            Singleton instance = Singleton.Instance
            _baseDate = Singleton.BaseDate;
            _baseEconomy = Singleton.BaseEconomy;
            // etc. etc.
        }
```

The line `Singleton instance = Singleton.Instance` is completely necessary in order to implement my singleton, however I don't think it's the fundamentally *correct* thing to do, since I never actually use the `instance` variable.

So how do I create an instance of a singleton for the sole purpose of having an instance in order to assign and access fields for each test class? Do I really need to assign it to a variable I'm never going to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `BaseDate` and `BaseEconomy` are static properties of your `Singleton` class you can use them without having instance of singleton. If these properties internally use instance of singleton, then you should not care about that - just use `Instance` property (instead of `instance` field) to access singleton instance inside these properties (if you have issues now, then you are using double-checked locking for singleton instance creation). So you don't need to retrieve reference to singleton object here:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    _baseDate = Singleton.BaseDate;
    _baseEconomy = Singleton.BaseEconomy;
    // etc. etc.
}
```

But consider to use instance properties instead. Thus you will have only one statically stored instance of singleton object you can store instance of this object and read it's `BaseDate` and `BaseEconomy` instance properties when you need them:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    _instance = Singleton.Instance;
}

[Test]
public void Foo()
{
   // use _instance.BaseDate 
   // use _instance.BaseEconomy
}
```

Comment: @HavelTheGreat as I stated, you should use `Instance` property in your static properties implementation instead of using `instance` field which can be uninitialized (in usual singleton implementation)

Comment: Sorry yeah I just saw your edit, that's exactly what I had in mind. Many thanks, it didn't seem to make sense I had to set all of those variables.

Comment: @HavelTheGreat keep in mind that with `private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();` implementation you will not have any problems with static properties